# How to list all data in Persistence

Tags: java, html, persistence

I have table named "Book" and I need to get the all data from book table. Then I need to visible all data in a html table. I made this using Java. Can anyone give me solution for this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Thanks for that valuable information. Go ahead.

Comment: @user2999888 Please try to read something related to spring,struts,hibernate and try by yourself, if you struck at time, we are here to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Spring JDBC templates to read the data. Use Spring MVC to present the data to the UI.